# How to search in vim cscope result window

Tags: vim, cscope

When we use cscope to go to definition of a symbol in vim, lots of candidates may be shown in result window. I'd like to perform searching within the window to find what I need quickly. But search function (/) doesn't seem to work in result window, only a few keys are available, j,k,gg,G, etc.

Is there anyway to search in cscope result window? Or can anyone share some experiences with how to work more efficiently in such a situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
" Filter the quickfix list
function! FilterQFList(type, action, pattern)
    " get current quickfix list
    let s:curList = getqflist()
    let s:newList = []
    for item in s:curList
        if a:type == 0     " filter on file names
            let s:cmpPat = bufname(item.bufnr)
        elseif a:type == 1 " filter by line content
            let s:cmpPat = item.text . item.pattern
        endif
        if item.valid
            if a:action < 0
                " Keep only nonmatching lines
                if s:cmpPat !~ a:pattern
                    let s:newList += [item]
                endif
            else
                " Keep only matching lines
                if s:cmpPat =~ a:pattern
                    let s:newList += [item]
                endif
            endif
        endif
    endfor
    call setqflist(s:newList)
endfunction
```

Then define four mappings (replace ø with something that fits for you, mine start with ð which I think might be unavailable on your keyboard) that map respectively to:

```
nnoremap ø :call FilterQFList(0, -1, inputdialog('Remove file names matching:', ''))<CR>
nnoremap ø :call FilterQFList(0, 1, inputdialog('Keep only file names matching:', ''))<CR>
nnoremap ø :call FilterQFList(1, -1, inputdialog('Remove all lines matching:', ''))<CR>
nnoremap ø :call FilterQFList(1, 1, inputdialog('Keep only lines matching:', ''))<CR>
```

This way you can filter your quickfix list with any pattern (you have the power of vim reg.exps). Use `:cnewer` and `:colder` to jump through previous quickfix lists.

Comment: Benoit, thanks for sharing. I can understand your script. But I don't get how to use it together with cscope. The output of cscope doesn't seem to go to quick fix window. Can you show how you make use of it?

Comment: Did you use `:cscope add my_cscope_database.out` then `:cscope find s your_symbol` ? Also make sure that `:set csqf=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-`. Also see `:help cscope-options`.

Comment: I didn't notice this option. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, do you know the "official name" of the default cscope output window?

Comment: It is called the quickfix window. See `:help quickfix`!

Comment: I know quickfix window. I mean what's the name of the default output window, which is used if I don't instruct cscope to use quickfix window.

Comment: Default is the location list window, which is the same as the quickfix window except that it works with commands of approximately the same name but with an `l` in front of the command (`:lnew`, `:lold`, `:ln`, etc.)